# I Get Prompted Once When I Have Two `getchar()` Statements In C

Tags: c, stdin, stdio

I'm having trouble understanding Input/Output, standard streams, stdin, EOF and other topics. My question is that when I run `getchar()` multiple times consecutively, one is cancelled:

```c
getchar();
getchar();
```

I expected it to prompt for input two times, but it only did once.
In higher level languages like Python, it is very easy to prompt multiple times:

```py
input()
input()
```

And when I run `getchar()` more than two times:

```c
getchar();
getchar();
getchar();
getchar();
getchar();
```

In this case, 5 times, I get prompted 3 times (at least for me, I tried it again and I still get prompted 3 times). I don't know what is going on, I even tried to put `sleep(1)` between the statements but I still get the same outcome.

I expect `getchar()` to be blocking, since it is in Canonical Mode. My hypothesis is that `getchar()` is somewhat asynchronous, and that the next statement is executed without waiting for the user to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**Info**:

- Shell: zsh
- OS: GNU/Linux

I'm just curious how `getchar()` works. (I also checked some Stack Overflow questions but none seemed to be related to my problem)

**EDIT: [SOLVED]**:

@Samarthya Singh's comment

I've even created a function that stops that from happening:

```c
int getch() {
  int c;
  c = getchar();
  if (c == '\n')
    return getchar();
  return c;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's taking the '\n' as the second character.

Comment: Yeah I think that's the reason, never thought about this. thanks

Comment: To keep your sanity, or at least to have robust input, use `getline` (POSIX, write your own for more portability) to read entire lines. Then parse the input from the string.

Comment: @TechTycho glad you managed to solve it. Consider answering to your question with the solution and to accept it as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

@Samarthya Singh's comment

> Maybe it's taking the '\n' as the second character.

I've even created a function that stops that from happening:

```c
int getch() {
  int c;
  c = getchar();
  if (c == '\n')
    return getchar();
  return c;
}
```